MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.24 MiB for an array with shape (12, 64, 255, 3) and data type float32
Jupyter Notebook cell in which i am getting error:
history = model.fit(tuple(train_generator), steps_per_epoch=num_train_examples//batch_size, epochs=500, callbacks=callbacks,\
                   validation_data=tuple(eval_generator), validation_steps=num_eval_examples//batch_size, verbose=1)

Snippet of code which the the model.fit() is accessing via tuple(train_generator) and tuple(eval_generator):
batch_y = self.y[list(sorted(used_indexes))]
        idx = []
        for i in range(0, len(is_horiz_flipped), 1):
            if batch_y.shape[1] == 1:
                if (is_horiz_flipped[i]):
                    batch_y[i] *= -1
                    
                if (np.isclose(batch_y[i], 0)):
                    if (np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1) > self.zero_drop_percentage):
                        idx.append(True)
                    else:
                        idx.append(False)
                else:
                    idx.append(True)
            else:
                if (batch_y[i][int(len(batch_y[i])/2)] == 1):
                    if (np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1) > self.zero_drop_percentage):
                        idx.append(True)
                    else:
                        idx.append(False)
                else:
                    idx.append(True)
                
                if (is_horiz_flipped[i]):
                    batch_y[i] = batch_y[i][::-1]

        batch_y = batch_y[idx]
        batch_x[0] = batch_x[0][idx]
        batch_x[1] = batch_x[1][idx]
        
        return batch_x, batch_y

Specific patch of code causing the error:
   332             batch_y[i] = batch_y[i][::-1]
    334 batch_y = batch_y[idx]
--> 335 batch_x[0] = batch_x[0][idx]
    336 batch_x[1] = batch_x[1][idx]
    338 return batch_x, batch_y

Screenshot of the error
link to the full code which model.fit() is using is here
I tried changing the paging file size in windows but still isn't working. Allocated almost of 80gb maximum file size still not working.

How much ram are you using. That message means you ran out of memory

i have 32 gb ram

Look at the task manager and see how much memory it is using when you run the command. What is it at?

Before executing its is around 7gb but after running it eventually reaches the limit and fails

I think we've found the source of your issue

is there any way to counter that?

Lower your epoch and steps per epoch
